# Windows is not booting & Ubuntu is running very slow  , may be due to bad partitioning

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, swap, ubuntu-16.04

have dual booted my lenovo laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10. I had no knowledge about partitioning at that time, so I left that task to Ubuntu thinking that it would do required tasks itself. But after dual booting I have lot of problems

1.Windows is not booting, when trying to reinstall it's showing:

**"drive where windows is installed is locked.unlock and try again"**

2.Ubuntu is running very slow. it is taking a minute even to boot

My Laptop has 7 partitions now.

```
1.Dev/sda1 **Size:**500 MB 
**Id**:7   **Type**:HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 
2.Dev/sda2 **Size:** 149. 8GB 
**Id:**82 **Type:** LinuxSwap/Polaris
 3.Dev/sda3 **Size:**390.6GB 
**Id:**7     **Type:**HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 
4.Dev/sda4  **Size:**390. 6GB 
**Id:**f    **Type:**W95 Ext'd (LBA) 
5.Dev/sda5   **Size:**193GB.
**Id:**7   **Type:**HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 
6.Dev/sda6    **Size:**7.9GB
 **Id:**82   **Type:**Linuxswap/polaris 
7.Dev/sda7    **Size:**189.7GB
 **Id:**83   **Type:**Linux
```

[Boot-info link is here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25613034/)

Comment: Regarding item #1 - Windows is probably safe.  You just need to get your computer to pass the boot process to the Windows partition.  Fixing this may take some time/expertise.  Those with such knowledge may be hesitant to help, just because it may take some time to explain things.  You definitely want to provide more details (like listing what partitions exist).  Regarding item #2 - That could be caused by bad partitioning (e.g., not making a partition large enough for swap to work effectively), but partitioning also might not be the cause.  So far we don't have enough details to know.

Comment: I suppose I just provided some details that may seem criticizing, but I didn't provide the solution.  In case the recommended solution wasn't obvious, here it is: Edit your question and include more details about what partitions exist.  (How big is each one?  What "partition type"/ID is used for each one?  What operating system is installed on each one?  What boot loader are you using?  etc.)  You can likely salvage all your data okay, if things are done right, so prepare to spend time on this, and expect that a very useful answer may be rather technical.

Comment: I have edited .Please suggest your solution

Comment: You will absolutely need a Windows installation medium to fix this. You can download the required files from Microsoft and create one, even on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I'd wipe and reinstall. Unless you have critical data that you can't afford to lose. But as a rule: before you start tinkering with disks you should back up your data just in case.

If you're using Windows 10 as your base, you could use VMWare or even Hyper-V for Ubuntu.  Hyper-V is free but will require that you use Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise and it is, admittedly, a pain to manage. But VMWare workstation is easy to install, easy to manage, and makes cloning VMs easy. But it does costs money.

In both cases your system must have have processor and BIOS support for virtualization but virtualization support goes back to Intel's Pentium 4 so you're probably fine on this front, still you should check if you're unsure.

Comment: I can't wipe because I  neither  have any Live usb nor can I create them.cant I resize the partitions using gparted in Ubuntu??

Comment: You don't need a live cd to load Linux into a VM,  just an iso. 

Yes, you can probably fix your machine using gparted. 

Friendly advice: if you don’t know what you’re doing, screwing with the HDD of a system is going to create headaches. Back in the day that was the only option; I discovered partitions by deleing the partition of my family’s computer. 

With virtualization you can learn and experiment on a VM  without compromising the stability of the host. You can also create snapshots and easily “roll back” to the point before you changed things so that you can try again.

Comment: Rob, can I wipe all the data on my laptop by installing Ubuntu agian.i think there's such an option during the installation process.I want to bring back my laptop to factory conditions